Optimization problem in $\mathbb{R}^N$ using vector calculus
I have an optimization problem in which I am trying to find an approximation of the closed form of the solution. My question lies in how to write a certain term in vector form so as to find the first order condition in vector form.
$A$ is a $N\times N$ positive definite and invertible matrix, $q$ and $v$ are vectors, the other parameters are scalars.
$$
\min_q -q'v + q'Aq + \sum^N_{k=1} ln(e^{a_k q_k + \mu_k}+e^{b_kq_k + \theta_k})
$$
I cannot manage to write the last part on vector form, I believe the F.O.C will not yield a closed form solution for $q^*$. So I was thinking of doing an orthogonal projection of the function I am trying to optimize onto the space of polynomials of degree up to two, do you think this could be a valid approach to find an approximate solution ?
Thank you !
